# SQL - Calculate the average of a value in a table B from date range in table A

Tags: sql

I am constructing a table in SQL like this

```
TABLE A    
obj_id start_date end_date
1      2021-03-01 2022-08-02
1      2020-06-01 2021-07-02
2      2021-05-03 2022-08-04
3      2021-04-21 2022-06-05
```

And I have another table

```
TABLE B
obj_id date        value
1      2021-04-12  21.45
3      2022-06-15  19.02
1      2020-11-02  3.11
2      2022-05-23  45.20
1      2022-07-31  32.45
3      2021-09-01  22.56
2      2021-10-10  34.04
```

I want to add to TABLE A a column with average value of TABLE B for corresponding obj_id of values where TABLE B date falls between TABLE A date range.

Expected result

```
TABLE A    
obj_id start_date end_date    average value
1      2021-03-01 2022-08-02  26.95         <-- Average value of 21.45 and 32.45 excluding 3.11 from average because date in table B is outside date range in table A
1      2020-06-01 2021-07-02  etc.
2      2021-05-03 2022-08-04  etc.
3      2021-04-21 2022-06-05  etc.
```

Comment: And what's your question about this? What have you tried to resolve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Sample query:

```
select 
    a.obj_id, 
    a.start_date, 
    a.end_date, 
    avg(b.value) as average 
from table_a a
inner join table_b b 
    on a.obj_id = b.obj_id 
    and b.date >= a.start_date 
    and b.date <= a.end_date 
group by 
    a.obj_id, 
    a.start_date, 
    a.end_date
order by 
    a.obj_id
```